# Android resource id for buttons not created in R.id after editing buttons' attributes. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I am trying to create a simple app with two buttons, a text field, and two linear layouts for practice. I am trying to create resource ids for the buttons. Here's my activity xml (activity_quiz.xml):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/true_button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/false_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/false_button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The issue is that the example I am following says that you should see these ids in R.id but I don't see them there. Here's the inner id class from R.java:

```
    public static final class id {
    public static final int action_bar=0x7f07001c;
    public static final int action_bar_activity_content=0x7f070014;
    public static final int action_bar_container=0x7f07001b;
    public static final int action_bar_overlay_layout=0x7f07001f;
    public static final int action_bar_root=0x7f07001a;
    public static final int action_bar_subtitle=0x7f070023;
    public static final int action_bar_title=0x7f070022;
    public static final int action_context_bar=0x7f07001d;
    public static final int action_menu_divider=0x7f070015;
    public static final int action_menu_presenter=0x7f070016;
    public static final int action_mode_close_button=0x7f070024;
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f07003c;
    public static final int activity_chooser_view_content=0x7f070025;
    public static final int always=0x7f07000f;
    public static final int beginning=0x7f07000a;
    public static final int checkbox=0x7f07002d;
    public static final int collapseActionView=0x7f070011;
    public static final int default_activity_button=0x7f070028;
    public static final int dialog=0x7f070012;
    public static final int disableHome=0x7f070008;
    public static final int dropdown=0x7f070013;
    public static final int edit_query=0x7f070030;
    public static final int end=0x7f07000c;
    public static final int expand_activities_button=0x7f070026;
    public static final int expanded_menu=0x7f07002c;
    public static final int home=0x7f070017;
    public static final int homeAsUp=0x7f070005;
    public static final int icon=0x7f07002a;
    public static final int ifRoom=0x7f07000e;
    public static final int image=0x7f070027;
    public static final int listMode=0x7f070001;
    public static final int list_item=0x7f070029;
    public static final int middle=0x7f07000b;
    public static final int never=0x7f07000d;
    public static final int none=0x7f070009;
    public static final int normal=0x7f070000;
    public static final int progress_circular=0x7f070018;
    public static final int progress_horizontal=0x7f070019;
    public static final int radio=0x7f07002f;
    public static final int search_badge=0x7f070032;
    public static final int search_bar=0x7f070031;
    public static final int search_button=0x7f070033;
    public static final int search_close_btn=0x7f070038;
    public static final int search_edit_frame=0x7f070034;
    public static final int search_go_btn=0x7f07003a;
    public static final int search_mag_icon=0x7f070035;
    public static final int search_plate=0x7f070036;
    public static final int search_src_text=0x7f070037;
    public static final int search_voice_btn=0x7f07003b;
    public static final int shortcut=0x7f07002e;
    public static final int showCustom=0x7f070007;
    public static final int showHome=0x7f070004;
    public static final int showTitle=0x7f070006;
    public static final int split_action_bar=0x7f07001e;
    public static final int submit_area=0x7f070039;
    public static final int tabMode=0x7f070002;
    public static final int title=0x7f07002b;
    public static final int top_action_bar=0x7f070020;
    public static final int up=0x7f070021;
    public static final int useLogo=0x7f070003;
    public static final int withText=0x7f070010;
}
```

I am using Android Studio and edited the activity xml in rev 23 and just updated to rev 23.0.1 If there is any other information that may help then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your resource Id names are "true_button" and "false_button" however, I wouldn't be looking into the R class for them since it is auto generated every time the project is built. I would recommend cleaning your project and rebuilding which should generate a new R class for your project and add those ids to the R class.

I also recommend Eclipse with ADT plugin but I understand if Android Studio is more favorable for you. I hope this helps, I have ran into this problem before and read about it in several books.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I usually use eclipse for other java projects but I'm new to android and android studio didn't have the same issues that eclipse adt bundle did with rev 23. I'll probably try eclipse again since rev 23.0.1 is out.

Comment: No problem. I have ran into this issue several times and have had to retrace my steps. Ironically, I decided to pick up a book recently that mentions this within the first chapter which many books never touch upon this topic. Android in Practice published by Manning. I highly recommend it.